# handling multiple select rows in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using the [React-Select library](https://react-select.com/home) to generate select options in react as you will see in the screenshot provided. The concept is simple, I have a button to add a new row that has a select options to input clients, the other input to insert date. Upon clicking on the plus button, it will add a new row to be filled with the exact info like i've explained. Please see the screenshot.
[image]

I have a problem filling up my state when the data changes for each row, so each object in the array represents a row, the following is my state

```
this.state = {
    customClients: [
     {
      date: null,
      clients: [{ value: "", label: "" }]
    }
    ]
  }
```

and this is a snippet of my render method

```
{this.state.customClients.map((client, i) => {
      let cli_id = `cli-${i}`;
      let date_id = `date-${i}`;
      return (
        <div className="row" key={i} id={i}>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <p className="mb-1 mt-3 font-weight-bold text-muted">Clients</p>
            <Select
              name="clients"
              inputId={cli_id}
              isMulti
              value={client.clients}
              onChange={this.handleCustomClients}
              options={clients || []}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-8">
            <div className="form-group">
              <p className="mb-1 mt-3 font-weight-bold text-muted">Date</p>
              <DatePicker
                name="date"
                id={date_id}
                className="form-control"
                selected={client.date}
                onChange={this.handleCustomClients}
                minDate={new Date()}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

Comment: what problem exactly you are facing?

Comment: What's in  `handleCustomClients`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing the object which recites inside array you need to pass the index of the record you want to edit. first let's update the `onChange` event and pass the index

```
<Select
        name="clients"
        inputId={cli_id}
        isMulti
        value={client.clients}
        onChange={e => this.handleCustomClients(e, i)}
        options={clients || []}
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
/>
```

And the method below

```
handleCustomClients(e, i) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return (prevState.customClients[i].clients = e);
    });
}
```

code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/rm1k8oor7o

Cheers!

Comment: This appears to no longer work with `react-select` version 5?  the onChange handler only returns `action` and `option`, no event object that I can find.